# Does the ticker plant pubsub work over websockets

Tags: kdb

I am trying to subscribe to realtime data from the ticker plan over a websocket.

I am using `.z.ws:{neg[.z.w] -8!value -9!x;}` as the ws handler.

I've tested the WebSocket mechanism connecting to rdb successfully.  Eg. simple 10#trade returns trade rows.  However, when I connect to ticker and attempt `.u.sub[`trade;`AAPL]` for example, via websocket, only one message comes and no subsequent updates come.

This works fine when I connect from another q process using hopen...

Comment: hey, we have Glen looking into this for you at the moment. He is just testing his solution now but will respond to you ASAP.

Comment: hey, he replied on the blog site there: http://www.aquaq.co.uk/q/kdb-websockets/. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`.u.sub` pumps via async so you need an async handler on the consumer side. The initial tick you get is just whatever the tickerplant has at that time. I don't think it matters whether you made the initial via websocket.

Try `.z.ps:{0!x;}` on the client q instance to see whats coming over async.

On the tickerplant you should see the client in the dictionary `.z.w`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  The client is a web browser, not a q process.  The websocket has a callback (onmessage) whenever there is data from q server.  I was hoping this would be called repeatedly with each update that would have called upd if it were a q client.